# ngx-onsenui latest version does not support in Angularv17

Tags: typescript, angular17

I am trying to upgrade an application from Angular 10 to Angular 17. I upgraded the Angular step by step using the migration document from Angular. But OnsenUI doesnot seem to work in angular 17. I am getting below errors:

```
......
.....

./node_modules/ngx-onsenui/fesm2015/ngx-onsenui.js:128:15-25 - Error: export 'PageLoader' (imported as 'PageLoader') was not found in 'onsenui' (possible exports: default)

./node_modules/ngx-onsenui/fesm2015/ngx-onsenui.js:352:42-52 - Error: export 'PageLoader' (imported as 'PageLoader') was not found in 'onsenui' (possible exports: default)

./node_modules/ngx-onsenui/fesm2015/ngx-onsenui.js:1080:25-53 - Error: export '_internal' (imported as '_internal') was not found in 'onsenui' (possible exports: default)

./node_modules/ngx-onsenui/fesm2015/ngx-onsenui.js:1080:104-132 - Error: export '_internal' (imported as '_internal') was not found in 'onsenui' (possible exports: default)

./node_modules/ngx-onsenui/fesm2015/ngx-onsenui.js:1229:15-25 - Error: export 'PageLoader' (imported as 'PageLoader') was not found in 'onsenui' (possible exports: default)

./node_modules/ngx-onsenui/fesm2015/ngx-onsenui.js:1341:15-25 - Error: export 'PageLoader' (imported as 'PageLoader') was not found in 'onsenui' (possible exports: default)

./node_modules/ngx-onsenui/fesm2015/ngx-onsenui.js:1407:24-36 - Error: export 'notification' (imported as 'notification') was not found in 'onsenui' (possible exports: default)

./node_modules/ngx-onsenui/fesm2015/ngx-onsenui.js:1414:20-28 - Error: export 'platform' (imported as 'platform') was not found in 'onsenui' (possible exports: default)

Error: src/app/app.module.ts:405:9 - error NG6002: 'OnsenModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

405         OnsenModule,
            ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/ngx-onsenui/lib/ngx-onsenui.d.ts:18:22
    18 export declare class OnsenModule {
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (ngx-onsenui) which declares OnsenModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

My package.json looks like this:

````
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^17.3.1",
    "async-lock": "^1.3.1",
    "convert-csv-to-json": "^1.3.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsqr": "^1.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "mustache": "^4.2.0",
    "ng-busy": "^17.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^17.0.0",
    "ngx-onsenui": "^7.1.0",
    "onsenui": "^2.12.8",
  },```

I am not sure how can I solve the issue??
````